# How to set autolayout constraint so that the height of an UIImageView is equal to the height of the superview?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I have created a `UIView` that consists of 3 `UILabel`s and 1 `UIImageView` as below -

[image: View]

The `UILabel`s have `lines` set to 0 so that the height of the `UILabel`s change dynamically

I have added constraints such that the height of the image depends on the height of the `UILabel`s as shown below -

[image]

I have set width of the `UIImageView` to a constant of 100.

I would like to set a constraint on `UIImageView` such that the height of the `UIImageView` is equal to the height of the whole view.

I tried adding a "Equal Heights" constraint on the `UIImageView` and the whole view. I observed that the height of the whole view depends on the height of the `UIImageView` and not that the height of the `UIImageView` depends on the whole view as I want it to be.

Can anyone point out how I can add a constraint to the `UIImageView` such that its height is equal to its superview but the height of the superview is not dependent on the `UIImageView`?

Edit - 
The below image shows the problem that I am facing. When an image is set to the `UIImageView`, the height of the view changes. 
I want the height of the `UIImageView` to be equal to the height of the view, but I do not want the height of the view to be dependent on height of the `UIImageView`

[image]

Comment: did you set any height constraint for view ?

Comment: what is the problem? It looks fine in the screenshot?

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya I have not set height constraint for the view, but I have set top and bottom constraints for the 3 labels so that height of the view is dependent on its subviews ( the 3 labels )

Comment: Did you try to add constraint for `Image bottom` is equal to `View bottom` ?

Comment: And, if those UILabel could have empty string, then you need to set a constraint for image about `minimum height`. For example, `Image Height >= 100`.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have added edit which shows screenshot of the problem that I am facing

Comment: @AechoLiu I have added constraint for `Image bottom` equal to `View bottom`. The problem is that view enlarges when image is added as I show in the screenshot that I have added in an edit

Comment: if you set top and bottom constrain then no need to heigh constraint

Comment: and you need to set vertical content hugging and compression resistance priority high of  labels

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya Yes, I needed to change vertical content compression resistance to get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to reduce the `vertical content compression resistance` on the image view.

Set it to something very low like 100 and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you haven't add the height constraint to the superview. Setup height constraint for the superview and then add a "Equal Heights" constraint on the UIImageView and the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

In fact default compression resistance of your `UIImageView` is 750, while content hugging of root `UIView` is 250. This means AutoLayout engine layouts everything correctly. You can change vertical compression resistance to value lower then 250 (`UILayoutPriority.defaultLow - 1`) to achieve desired layout.